# How to have react native children within swift components

Tags: swift, react-native

is it possible to pass react native components to a swift component? I was referring to this tut https://shopify.engineering/creating-native-components-accept-react-native-subviews but it only shows android support.

Something like this:

```
const MyNativeModule = requireNativeComponent('MyNativeModule');

return (
  <View>
    <MyNativeModule icon={<Image ... />}>
      <View />
    </MyNativeModule>
  </View>
)
```